# Unreadable text using setCustomValidity on password field in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

If I set an error message using setCustomValidity on an html5 form password field, it pops up as bubbles or stars, just like the password field itself, resulting in an unreadable message.

Here's a jsfiddle for demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/LcfuQ/1/

This works in Firefox 4, but I get this strange behavior using Google Chrome. Anyone know of a workaround, or some way to fix this?

**EDIT: This has been fixed in version 12+**

Comment: Have you tried this in the Chrome dev channel? The jsfiddle you've linked to is working fine for me in 12.0.733.0, so this might just be a bug that's fixed, but not yet trickled down into the stable channel.

Comment: Indeed, this is fixed in dev channel. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a problem with Chrome

When the input type="password", asterisks are shown in the place of characters even for HTML5.

See this fiddle in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/idiotsden/RdwMw/  . It works in ff4.

The workaround is to use jquery tools. You can see the working tutorial here

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/custom-validators.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a WebKit bug with the `-webkit-text-security` CSS property, which can't be overridden. It's likely already been reported on the [WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/), but if it isn't you might want to report it.